# Position:Absolute; Div is making the page too wide and adding blank space to the side. How do I reduce its size?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am currently working on the site at http://crowfell.com/index2.php, if you enter a username into the log in form and log in a player profile appears in the top-right corner. When a user isn't logged in the page is fine, but once they've logged in the player profile div creates a 100% width div that starts at the right side of the page, extending it unnecessarily to the right into blank space.

How can I stop a position:absolute div from having a 100% width?

This is created using the following code:

HTML/PHP:

```
<div class='fixed'>
    <?php
        echo "<h1>" . $_SESSION['name'] . "</h1>";
        include 'comp.php';
    ?>
    <p>0 posts, 0 votes</p>
</div>
<div class='userimg'>
    <img src='images/user.jpg'>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed { 
    /*font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;*/
    width: 160px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin-left: 86%;
}

.userimg { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    margin-left: 78%;
}
```

The PHP file in the include is simply a random complement generator and adds a short line, which is only affected by the div css.

I have tried adding width:20%; to each css style, I have also tried giving it a low left value, adding overflow:hidden;, as well as containing the two divs in a third and giving that different width and overflow properties. None have worked!

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: To check the issue we need to login, can you show us an example page?

Comment: If you follow the log in link in the top of the page there is no database backend, it's just a demonstration site atm. Just log in with anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it harder than it has to be with your `left` and `margin-left` on your `fixed` and `userimg` classes.

Try this CSS instead.  Remove the `left` and `margin-left` on both of them and use

```
.fixed {
  color: #EEEEEE;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 0;
  width: 160px;
}
.userimg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 180px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

Now you're making them relative to each other on the right side of the screen instead of trying to **bump** from the left.

Comment: Thanks, but this still hasn't worked. 
`.fixed { 
 /*font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;*/
 color: #eeeeee;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
 right: 0;
}

.userimg { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
 right: 180px;
}`
Is my code now, but the width of the div is still creating a huge blank space to the right.

Comment: That's not true.  You have NO positioning set on those elements.  I just viewed source and the only thing set is the top and right.

Comment: I know, it doesn't make sense to me. It is still happening and it is definitely those elements causing it, there is no width defined in any of the surrounding CSS but when I try and change the width so it doesn't go over the side of the page nothing happens and the page remains annoyingly wide - I'm completely stumped.

Comment: No, I'm saying you don't have the CSS correct.  You no longer have `position: absolute` set for .fixed or for .userimg.  Fix that and it'll work.  I just used firebug to modify your CSS then copy the rules and I edited my post to include the **FULL** CSS for each of the two.  With that CSS in place, it works, no matter how wide I make the screen.

Comment: Aha, yes I see what you mean now. Thanks very much!